# How to get these PHP includes working?

Tags: php, path, include

I've got the following file structure:

```
/
+--- inc/
|    +--- lib1.php
+--- inc2/
|    +--- lib2.php
|    +--- view2.php
+--- view1.php
```

Both view1.php and view2.php include lib2.php. Lib2.php includes lib1.php. Graphically:

```
View1.php ---\
             +---> Lib2.php ---> Lib1.php
View2.php ---/
```

However I cannot get this working, because the search paths are wonky. If I try to include "../lib1.php" then only view2.php works. If I try to include "inc/lib1.php", then only view1.php works. The other view always complains about file not found.

What should be the correct way of handling this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use php >= 5.3 you can use `__DIR__` to build the path. If not, use `dirname(__FILE__)`
So in lib2.php, just put this:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '../inc/lib1.php');
```

Comment: If you use '../' only, it's relative to the working directory the script is executed in, so using `__FILE__` or `__DIR__` is an easy way to achieve what you're actually looking for. Docs are here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Glad you like it! And glad they introduced `__DIR__`, the other solution looked a bit weird.

Comment: Everybody loves `__DIR__`, looks like it was about time :)

Comment: @hakre "So in lib2.php, just put this [...]" - problem with that. You're instructing the reader to add what amounts to a self-include, which will definitely confuse them. You may want to edit for clarity.

Comment: @Obsidian_ : I think you were adressing to me, glad you noticed that problem!

Answer (score 1):

In your user facing files, define a constant like so (assuming PHP 5.3 here):

```
<?php
define('ROOT_INCLUDE_PATH', __DIR__ . '/');
```

Now, in any file within your project that is included by your user facing files, you just use a simple include.

This next snippet would be view1.php:

```
<?php
define('ROOT_INCLUDE_PATH', __DIR__ . '/');
// ...
include ROOT_INCLUDE_PATH . 'inc/lib1.php';
include ROOT_INCLUDE_PATH . 'inc2/lib2.php';
```

And this would be view2.php (note that we use `dirname()` here to make the root path up a directory):

```
<?php
define('ROOT_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__) . '/');
// ...
include ROOT_INCLUDE_PATH . 'inc/lib1.php';
include ROOT_INCLUDE_PATH . 'inc2/lib2.php';
```

This means that your includes can include other includes without any modifications at all; so long as you define the root include path appropriately in your user-facing files, it's all good.

Comment: +1 for this project root path design, but what do you mean by "user facing files"?

Comment: @greg0ire anything that the user interacts with directly; it's the polar opposite of an include file, a library file that the user never accesses (but is included at runtime).  it's basically THE page the user is sending the request to.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  That should be dirname(), not basename().  /me edits

Answer (score 0):

Since relying on a relative path won't work, I think that a possible solution is to use an absolute path. Declare `$system_path = "/"` as a global variable, so you can always include based on the system path.

Comment: Even this works, it prevents the code from being portable, e.g. when you put it onto another system.

Comment: It's actually better to do that as a constant, not a global variable.